# EF One-To-One and One-To-Many between same entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have the following problem: I need to create entities, which will be connected with One-To-Many and One-To-One relationships in Entity Framework at the same time.

The model I want to create is following: I have MapObject entity and there FloorMap entity. There are many MapObjects on the FloorMap, but FloorMap is a part of another MapObject. How can I implement it?

I thought about doing somtheing like this:

```
public class FloorMap
{

    public int FloorMapID { get; set; }

    public int FloorNumber { get; set; }

    public string FloorImage { get; set; }

    public string FloorMapDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MapObject> MapObjects { get; set; }

    public virtual MapObject MapObject { get; set; }
}

public partial class MapObject
{
    [Key,ForeignKey ("FloorMap")]
    public int FloorMapRefID { get; set; }

    public virtual FloorMap FloorMap { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work the way I want it to. Is there any way to implement such relationships in EF?

Comment: I don't think it works that way, especially because EF maps 1-to-1 relationships through FK=PK. to implement it, you could put it all in a 1-to-many relationship and put a flag on the one you want in the 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: *that doesn't work* Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure I understand what you are asking but it sounds like you want a floor map to have one parent and many children. Im not too sure why you want MapObject in the mix with this but sure.

```
public class FloorMap
{
    public int FloorMapID { get; set; }
    public int FloorNumber { get; set; }
    public string FloorImage { get; set; }
    public string FloorMapDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MapObject> MapObjects { get; set; }
    public virtual MapObject MapObject { get; set; }
}

public partial class MapObject
{
    [Key,ForeignKey ("FloorMap")]
    public int FloorMapRefID { get; set; }
    public virtual FloorMap FloorMap { get; set; }
    public int OtherFloorMapRefID {get;set;}
    public virtual FloorMap OtherFloorMap { get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<FloorMap>().HasMany(e => e.MapObjects).WithRequired(e=>e.OtherFloorMap).HasForeignKey(e=>e.OtherFloorMapRefID);
modelBuilder.Entity<FloorMap>().HasOptional(e => e.MapObject).WithRequired(e=>e.FloorMap);
```

Does this look like what you are trying to do?